# Reproduce the shell pipe command

Tags: c, pipe, file-descriptor

I have a school project which consists of reproducing the shell pipe command between two commands that the operator will choose as it pleases.

```
./pipex infile "ls -l" "wc -l" outfile
```

should be equivalent to

```
< infile ls -l | wc -l > outfile
```

Roles of my find_path function:

- extract the contents of PATH from the envp
- use split() to delimit the paths according to ":" and store them in a double pointer
- use strjoin() to append a "/" to the end of each path, and add the user command
- test each path with access() then return the valid path

```
char    *find_path(char *cmd, char **envp)
{
    char        **array_of_paths;
    char        *path_ultime;
    int         i;
    char        *temp;

    i = 0;
    while (ft_strnstr(envp[i], "PATH=", 5) == 0)
        i++;
    array_of_paths = ft_split(envp[i] + 5, ':');
    i = 0;
    while (array_of_paths[i])
    {
        temp = ft_strjoin(array_of_paths[i], "/");
        path_ultime = ft_strjoin(temp, cmd);
        free(temp);
        if (access(path_ultime, F_OK | X_OK) == 0)
            return (path_ultime);
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

My main takes care of:

- split the argv[2] and the argv[3] with a space as delimiter, to keep only the command "ls" or "wc", and not the options
- classic stuff like pipe(), fork(), execve() …

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char **envp)
{
    (void)argc;

    pid_t   pid1;
    pid_t   pid2;
    int     fd[2];
    char    **cmd_and_options1;
    char    **cmd_and_options2;
    char    *path_ultime1;
    char    *path_ultime2;

    cmd_and_options1 = ft_split(argv[2], ' ');
    cmd_and_options2 = ft_split(argv[3], ' ');
    path_ultime1 = find_path(cmd_and_options1[0], envp);
    path_ultime2 = find_path(cmd_and_options2[0], envp);

    if (pipe(fd) == -1)
        return (1);

    pid1 = fork();

    if (pid1 == -1)
        return (1);

    if (pid1 == 0) // First child
    {
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execve(path_ultime1, cmd_and_options1, envp);
    }

    pid2 = fork();
    
    if (pid2 == -1)
        return (1);

    if (pid2 == 0) // Second child
    {
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execve(path_ultime2, cmd_and_options2, envp);
    }

    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);

    waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0);
    waitpid(pid2, NULL, 0);

    return (0);
}
```

A friend told me that I lacked the management of the input and output file (argv[1] and argv[4]) that the operator will enter but I don't really understand what that means.

I know I have to use open() somewhere...

Can you give me some clues?

Comment: A proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would increase your chances of receiving help. There is a lot of fragmented code here, when the onus is on you to provide examples that are easy to compile. Additionally, you have not asked a *specific* question - if your program works well, what is the problem?

Comment: I made changes.

The problem is that I don't manage the input and output files (argv[1] and argv[4]) that the user will enter, and I don't see how to do it.

Comment: You don't have to mess with the `PATH` environment variable, `execlp` or `execvp` already does the lookup for you. If `argv[2]` and `argv[3]` are supposed to be proper shell commands, you don't have to split the strings on space yourself, the shell might do it for you with `/c`. (This will also take care of the `PATH` lookup). If you want to do the `PATH` lookup yourself, you shouldn't test using `access`. Things might change between testing and executing. You should test by doing the actual exec. If the exec fails, you have to check the reason and either log an error, or try the next path.

Comment: @Itsme You're already showing that you know how to replace `stdin`/`stdout` with the file descriptors of the two ends of a pipe. What's different about opening the file paths provided, and replacing the correct file descriptors with those file descriptors?

Comment: To handle input from files you have to do `int fd = open(...)`; And after error checking, do a `dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO); close(fd)` and some more error checking. Doing it in the appropriate child process is probably a good idea. Similar for output to file.

Comment: Oh, and to lookup environment variables, don't mess with `envp`. Every non-ancient c-implementation should have `getenv`